# EXCEL - Array formula match in list

Tags: excel

I am trying to make a formula that returns into a single cell (array formula) a vector of True/False based on whether each element in an array matches (identically) or not any of the elements in another array.

Example:

Array to be matched (array_compare): [A;A;B;C;D]

Array with elements (array_elements): [A;B;D]

The formula should return something like:

`={formula(array_compare;array_elements)} ==> [TRUE;TRUE:TRUE;FALSE;TRUE]`

I need this mid-step function so later on I can add rows or columns based on criteria or tell how many matching item there are in array_compare.

For example (for later use):

`=sum(--formula(array_compare;array_elements))} ==> 4` (in the example)

THANKS!

Comment: What is your end goal? Sounds like an X-Y problem. A cell can't hold an array like what you're looking for.

Comment: Of course it can (array formula). So later on, for example, i could do ={sum(--formula(array_compare;array_elements))}, which in the above case it will yield 3

Comment: What is your end goal here? SUM on an array is not the same as *just an array in a single cell* (which is not possible).

Comment: In your example, why does `D` return `FALSE`? Shouldn't it be `TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE`?

Comment: So why only 3, does not the A match twice?

Comment: the example is corrected now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ISNUMBER(MATCH())

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH({"A","A","B","C","D"},{"A","B","D"},0)))
```

This will return `4` as it will iterate the large array.

If you want to iterate the smaller array reverse the two arrays and it will return `3`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(MATCH({"A","B","D"},{"A","A","B","C","D"},0)))
```